# Invalid template iteration for value `[object Object]` in It must be an array-like object

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
{
  "channelDescription": "Free web building tutorials",
  "channelLink": "https://www.w3schools.com",
  "channelTitle": "W3Schools Home Page",
  "itemLst": [
    {
      "description": "New RSS tutorial on W3Schools",
      "link": "https://www.w3schools.`[![enter code here][1]][1]`com/xml/xml_rss.asp",
      "title": "RSS Tutorial"
    },
    {
      "description": "New XML tutorial on W3Schools",
      "link": "https://www.w3schools.com/xml",
      "title": "XML Tutorial"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my json

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-size_3-of-4">
        <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
            <template for:each={responsedata} for:item="item">
                <li key={item.channelTitle}>
                    <b style="color:cornflowerblue">{item.channelTitle}</b>
                </li>
                </template>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>



import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
import getparseResponseDom from '@salesforce/apex/RssFeedCtrl.getparseResponseDom';

export default class RssFeedView extends LightningElement {
    @track responsedata = [{}];    
    @track dataArr = [];  
    connectedCallback(){        

        getparseResponseDom({ })
            .then(res => {
                this.responsedata = res;

                console.log('==11=='+JSON.stringify(this.responsedata));


            })
            .catch(error => {

            });
    }
}
```

When I am iterating here I am getting the above error.

Comment: Can you edit and paste clearer code also the html file content?

Comment: Please us the `{}` tool in the editor to format your code, or wrap each block in triple backticks (```).

Answer (score 2):

```
@track responsedata = [{}];
```

Should be:

```
@track responsedata = {};
```

And

```
<template for:each={responsedata} for:item="item">
```

Should be:

```
<template is:true={responsedata.itemLst} for:each={responsedata.itemLst} for:item="item">
```

And

```
<li key={item.channelTitle}>
```

Should be:

```
<li key={item.link}>
```

Comment: And the key attribute should be changed as well to something unique maybe `key={item.link}`

Comment: @manjit5190 Thanks for the catch. I totally missed that.